# Create object with Switch Statement: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method?

Tags: java, enums, static, switch-statement, non-static

I have trying to create an object based on the `type` using switch statement. However I am getting this error on the method in main method:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   CreateCoffee(CoffeeFactory.Type) from the type CoffeeFactory

```
public Coffee CreateCoffee(Type t ) {
    ingred = null;

    switch (t) {
     case LONG_BLACK:  
         ingred.add(Ingredient.ESPRESSO);
         return new Coffee(ingred, t);
     case FLAT_WHITE: 
         ingred.add(Ingredient.MILK);
         return new Coffee(ingred, t);
     case MOCHA: 
         ingred.add(Ingredient.CHOCOLATE);
         return new Coffee(ingred, t);

    default: return null;
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CreateCoffee(Type.MOCHA);
}
```

what am i doing wrong, is it the `return new Coffee()` statement in each switch case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `CreateCoffee` method static as it is referenced directly from the `main` method which is static.

Answer (score 1):

static enables you to call a method without creating any object.so if you're calling a static method in this case main then you can call methods with the help of objects or you can call other static methods.